# what is javascript regex to validate an array of string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongoose

I want to validate an array of a single element of type string using regex. The array should not be empty and should not start with any special symbol except # and the string can include only numbers and alphabets.

what i tried
[a-zA-z0-9s!@#$%^&*()_/\+=.,~`]+

Comment: Try: `#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
regex = /^#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
regex = /^#?[a-z0-9]+/gi;
```

Breakdown:

```
/^ - Match the start of the string
#? - Match an optional #
[a-z0-9] - Character set including the lowercase alphabet, and all ten digits
+ - Match one or more of the preceding character set
/gi - Global and case-insensitive flags
```